# How is the relationship between Scripts and Objects in Unity?

Tags: unity, scripting, objects

1. If I don't attach the Script to the Object, will be the code able to "see" the object?
2. When I need to manipulate (such as enabled() or a transform()) two or more Objects, do I need to attach the Script to both or just one?

I'm very confused on this subject because I don't need to specify which GameObject I'm targeting when the script it's attached, but there's also the Find() function which appear to do the same.

Comment: Scripts only run if they are added to a GameObject. `Find` returns the first result Unity finds, but this might not be the result you want if there are multiple possible results. For manipulating multiple objects, you could have a script only affect the GameObject it's attached to, or you could have a single script that controls multiple GameObjects, perhaps using `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` or adding your desired GameObjects to a List and looping through each entry to do as you please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties like `transform` or `gameObject` are shortcuts for `GetComponent<Transform>()`.
So yes, the GameObject your script is attached to is the Object the script "sees".
To your second question im not sure what you mean with manipulate but most of the time the
answer is yes. MonoBehaviours should (mostly) only affect the GameObjects they're attached to.

To the Find method you mentioned, i guess you mean the `GameObject.Find` method, you should not use it. Has bad performance and if you want a reference on a different GameObject just add a field to your MonoBehaviour and drag-n-drop the object you want to access in the inspector.

For more questions about the script system or other stuff in Unity feel free to ask me.

Comment: So, I should attach the script to the GameObject instead of using Find (or FindWithTag, etc)?

Comment: Yes exactly. Otherwise it would be a central game manager which is not very object oriented.

Comment: `GameObject.Find` has bad performance if you are doing it hundreds of times per frame. If you just need to find something once in a while it is a perfect viable solution.

Comment: Thats right but anyways its not good because you search by name and names can change. And the Unity Editor already supports many ways to get the reference of the GameObject you want to find. `GameObject.Find` is an old way, not very scalable and easily avoidable.

Comment: Could you please provide a example where is better to use a FindWithTag  (or other variations) than attach the script to multiple objects?

Comment: There are none. The only ones existing are when you want to iterate through a number of GameObjects with the same tag. But thats just for laziness, there are better ways to find GameObjects with the same tags.